# ZFS: Sharing a large number of data sets

Tags: nfs, zfs

I have a situation where I have a zfs pool with a large number of data sets (>8000 and counting) on a single machine.

The structure of these data sets can be simplified as follows:

1. data/1
2. data/2
3. data/3
4. ...
5. data/8000
6. ...

There is only one level of nesting as seen above.

I would like to be able to mount these data sets on another machine.

Using sharenfs=on on the root data set doesn't seem to work anymore for this large number of data sets. zfs seems to make each data set its own nfs mount point. It seems the nfs protocol cannot cope with this large number of data sets. Simply listing all the directories takes forever.

Manually sharing the root folder using nfs doesn't seem to work either. I can then list all the directories really fast, but they're all empty and have the wrong permissions.

So I am currently looking for a solution for this.

Would it be, for example, possible to somehow configure zfs to only share the root data set as an nfs mount point, but still maintain access to all the child data sets that inherited their local mount point from the root data set?

Mounting and unmounting things on the fly is not an option for me for performance reasons.

Comment: As far as I know, you've explored all the options (other than changing the filesystem structure to reduce how many filesystems you have; you could make it have N >=1 filesystems with 8000/N directories inside each of them).

Comment: In general, listing many directories over NFS is always going to suck no matter whether they're using different mountpoints or not (although that could make it worse). The network latency becomes a huge problem because each syscall will be called in series (unless there is a new parallel version of "ls" that I don't know about :)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was mainly checking whether there wasn't any obvious solution that I have missed. If you say I tried the most obvious ones, then it seems I have to go to the drawing table and work out a solution for this myself. The listing of all directories isn't an operation the system needs to support in every day usage, but it did reveal the problem that having too many data sets mounted is a problem, which is something that could happen in production.